# PGAdmin does not show indexes

Tags: properties, pgadmin

How can I see indexes in PGAdmin via properties dialog? I am sure index is there as you can see on the picture, but in properties dialog I can not find that index.
[image][image]

Comment: Maybe better asked on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I really dont know the difference. I only differs Stackoverflow, Superuser and AskUbuntu. Its too much.